# why nodejs simple counter on openshift counts twice?

Tags: javascript, node.js, openshift

I'm using OpenShift as a server for my nodejs app. when i look into my logs (live) after every refresh i see that 2 numbers are added:

```
server running
0
1
```

then after another refresh:

```
server running
0
1
2
3
```

this is the code on my server:

```
var http = require('http');
var server_port = proccess.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080;
var server_addr = proccess.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1';
var i = 0;

http.createServer(function(req,res){
  res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('hello world');
  console.log(i++);
}).listen(server_port,server_addr);

console.log('server running');
```

am i missing something? why the counter keeps increasing by 2 after each refresh?
thanks!

Comment: Try using a `return` statement after the `console.log(i++)`, see if that works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are responding to every single request with the hello world and count. I imagine you are doing this from a browser. Basically the browser, by default, will require `/favicon.ico` to show a favicon in the tab.

This is why it increases twice.

Comment: that's a good point!! i should have look on the network tab in devtools. thank you very much!